# Unknown message while debugging in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-debugging

Today while i was debugging my code step by step i encountered one message while debugging my ASP.net web api.

[image: Unknown Debugging Message]

I had never encountered any such message. What is this message and why it came, what is the main purpose of it. Can anybody explain.

Comment: It will only show when the compiler skip some object or method, and it's normal in step-over button `(F10)`, It's also occurred when you are not allowed to Step-Into `(F11)` in object or method.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is asking that its **going to skip some code and debug your program**. And this message is to ask that do you need to be informed whenever this happens.

If you want to be informed in future,  you can select "Yes" otherwise select "No"

You can simply ignore this and continue.